# Splash screen-Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-splashscreen

I want to integrate a splash screen in my android jetpack compose project . The screen has a background image and an icon at the center. I have tried splash screen api recommended in this [official link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen).

But this troubles me out because we cant add the background image or any custom layout on theme specified for splash screen. I just found docs to add a background color and icon.
Also it does not work for devices run below android 12.

When i try to use normal activity as a launcher and handle splash screen logics manually, the app is giving a blank screen at the start up.I have tried it just in an empty compose project also, so its nothing about startup load .
I have also added this themes.xml

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

I want to have this splash integrated which will work on above nougat devices and also the app startup wont give a blank screen at the startup.
What is the best approach for this ?

Comment: You can refer this link for android 12 or below: https://developersancho.medium.com/jetpack-compose-splash-screen-api-36ca40c6196b

Comment: The Splash Screen APIs work back to API 14.